Number of non-zero one- and two-body integrals in second quantization Hamiltonian
The electronic Hamiltonian of a molecule with Born-Oppenheimer approximation in second quantization is given by
$$\hat{\mathcal{H}}_{el} = \sum_{p,q} h_{pq}  \hat{c}_{p}^{\dagger} \hat{c}_{q} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{p,q,r,s} h_{pqrs} \hat{c}_{p}^{\dagger} \hat{c}_{q}^{\dagger} \hat{c}_{r} \hat{c}_{s}$$
with the one- and two-body integrals
$$h_{pq}= \langle \phi_{p}| \hat{T}_{e} + \hat{U}_{en}| \phi_{q} \rangle = \int \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} \phi_{p}^{*}(\mathbf{r}) \left( -\frac{1}{m_e}\nabla^2_{\mathbf{r}} - \sum_{I} \frac{Z_{I}}{| \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{R}_{I} |} \right)\phi_{q}(\mathbf{r}) \\ h_{pqrs}= \langle \phi_{p} \phi_{q}| \hat{U}_{ee}| \phi_{r} \phi_{s} \rangle = \int \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r'} \phi_{p}^{*}(\mathbf{r}) \phi_{q}^{*}(\mathbf{r'}) \left( \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|} \right)\phi_{r}(\mathbf{r'})\phi_{s}(\mathbf{r})$$
where $\phi_p (r)$ is the function of the molecular orbital $p$.
How many (non-zero) terms does the Hamiltonian have when a basis set of size $M$ is chosen?
Naively, just by counting the number of combinations, I would expect there to be $M^2$ $h_{pq}$ elements and $M^4$ $h_{pqrs}$ elements. But some of them evaluate to zero. Given an orthogonal basis set and the molecules symmetries, which considerations allow to identify terms that will evaluate to zero without explicit calculation of the integral?
Background for the question:

For example, in the Python package PennyLane Qchem, the indices for the fermionic operators, given some numbers for the integrals will not include any pair $(i,i+1)$. Where does this come from?
When using a package to calculate a molecular Hamiltonian, the number of terms in some cases does not scale with the number of electrons in the molecule. How?


It depends on the basis set chosen, no?
